# Can I use the Java library of the Telegram API source in PhoneGap to develop for both Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, telegram

I'm currently developing an app using PhoneGap. This app will make use of the Telegram API to provide a messaging system. **Should I just use the Java library or do I also need to make use of the Telegram for iOS source?**

Answer (score 2):

If you develop Phonegap you must implement all client-side functionalities with Javascript. Also keep in mind that since you will be making request to Telegrams domain, you have to make cross-domain requests so you could look at an example using Twitter here: http://samcroft.co.uk/2010/loading-data-into-a-phonegap-app/

Or if you prefer another aproach using Phonegap, whitelist the domain, info here: [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.htmle](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to put the telegram web UI (https://github.com/zhukov/webogram) into phonegap or cordova.